# get name of treeitem Javafx

Tags: javafx, treeview

I want to get name of each treeitem node and the parents for each, then put them in treemap, but when I run this sample code I get these result as values :

```
[TreeItem [ value: Function 12 ], TreeItem [ value: Function 13 ]]
[TreeItem [ value: Function 6 ]]
[TreeItem [ value: Function 15 ]]
[TreeItem [ value: Function 9 ], TreeItem [ value: Function 10 ]]
```

How can I get ride of extra things [TreeItem [ value: ] I just want the string like Function 12

```
    ArrayList<String> kids = new ArrayList<>();
    TreeMap<String, List<String>> parentChild = new TreeMap<>();
    for (TreeTableColumn<String, ?> tt : treeTable.getColumns()) {

        for (TreeItem node : root.getChildren()) {

            if (!node.isLeaf()) {
                     parentChild.put(node.getValue().toString(),node.getChildren());
            }
        }
    }
    for(Entry<String, List<String>> ent : parentChild.entrySet())
        System.out.println(ent.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is the following:

```
parentChild.put(node.getValue().toString(),node.getChildren());
```

You are adding the node.getChildren(), which has the return value of an `ObservableList<TreeItem<T>>`. And you are adding this to a TreeMap with Value List. You should change your map to

```
TreeMap<String, List<TreeItem<String>>> myMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

After that you can loop through it later on with:

```
for(TreeItem node: root.getChildren(){
   parentChild.put(node.getValue().toString(), node.getChildren());
}

for(Entry<String, List<TreeItem>> ent: parentChild.entrySet(){
    for(TreeItem myItem : ent.getValue()){
        System.out.println(myItem.getValue());
    }
}
```

This should print your "Function X" strings.

Comment: can I get a TreeMap<Parent, list of children> here?

Comment: Im not sure what you want to achieve with this, but of course you can just hold a TreeMap<TreeItem<String>, List<TreeItem<String>>> and save Parent Node and the children of it.

Comment: well i want to do this http://stackoverflow.com/q/29007045/4262423    I will try it as you said

Comment: This the out put {Function 1=[], Function 11=[TreeItem [ value: Function 12 ], TreeItem [ value: Function 13 ]], Function 3=[], Function 4=[], Function 5=[TreeItem [ value: Function 6 ]], Function 7=[TreeItem [ value: Function 15 ]], Function 8=[TreeItem [ value: Function 9 ], TreeItem [ value: Function 10 ]]}

Comment: One problem is that Function 11 has in fact 3 children for example ( function 13 has a child itself(function 14) which i need to have it as function 11 as well. And I should of course omit TreeItem stuff as you said formerly.